# microsoft orleans how to IServiceCollection replace to Castle Windsor

Tags: orleans

I'm using Microsoft Orleans
I want to replace an IServiceCollection with Castle Windsor

```
.ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext,services) => 
{
    var abpBootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<LimsServerModule>();
    abpBootstrapper.Initialize();
    WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(abpBootstrapper.IocManager.IocContainer, services);
});
```

This code does not take effect

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow,com, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ISiloHostBuilder` and `IClientBuilder` interfaces have a method, `UseServiceProviderFactory`, which allows you to specify your service provider.

There is an example of how to use this method with Autofac in the test suite here: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/62c1869b906f33def5ee0eb107365de5e8e24996/test/DependencyInjection.Tests/Autofac/DependencyInjectionGrainTestsUsingAutofac.cs#L31

The same pattern applies to Castle Windsor.